# save edit buttons on same form in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

i have simple form,i want to save the data and edit the data by giving first value in the same form.i able to save the data but coming to edit i have problem,i think i follow correct approach but i am unable to find the problem and i did't get any error,i drop my total code please solve this issue

index.jsp:

```
  <body>
 <%String status;
  status=(String)session.getAttribute("edit");
if(status=="fail")
{%>
<h6>there are no records with this no</h6>
<% }
%> 
   <form action="indexaction.jsp" method="post">
   Id <input type="text" name="id" id="id2"><br>
   <%
   if(status=="success")
   {%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsById("id2").value='<%=request.getAttribute("id1")%>';
   </script>
   <%} %>
   Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name2"><br>
   <%
   if(status=="success")
   {%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsById("name2").value='<%=request.getAttribute("name1")%>';
   </script>
   <%} %>
   sex <input type="text" name="sex" id="sex2"><br>
   <%
   if(status=="success")
   {%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsById("sex2").value='<%=request.getAttribute("sex1")%>';
   </script>
   <%} %>
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="save">
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="edit">
   </form>
  </body>
```

indexaction.jsp:

```
<body>

 <%!

 PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
  int id1;
  String name1,sex1;
  %>

  <%
  Connection connection=DBCreation.getConnection();
  String action=request.getParameter("action");
  int i=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
  String name=request.getParameter("name");
  String sex=request.getParameter("sex");

  if(action.equals("save")){

  preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into sample values(?,?,?)");
  preparedStatement.setInt(1, i);
  preparedStatement.setString(2, name);
  preparedStatement.setString(3, sex);
  int j=preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
  if(j>0)
  {
    out.println("<h3>inserted success</h3>");
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
  }
  }
  else if(action.equals("edit")){
  int x=0;
  System.out.println("edit called");
  preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("select * from sample where id=?");
  preparedStatement.setInt(1, i);
  ResultSet resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();

  while(resultSet.next())
  {
  x++;
  request.getSession().setAttribute("edit", "success");
  System.out.println("while called"+x);
   id1=resultSet.getInt(1);
   name1=resultSet.getString(2);
  sex1=resultSet.getString(3);

  request.setAttribute("id1", id1);
  request.setAttribute("name1",name1);
  request.setAttribute("sex1", sex1);
  }


  if(x<=0)
        {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("edit", "fail");

        }

  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
   %>
  </body>
</html>
```

with this code   if i enter wrong id i got error message "there are no records with this no",means it is working fine because of status 'fail' is setted . if i enter correct id  the problem comes.thanku

Comment: what u get if u enter correct id?

Comment: thanks for response,no errors in console and i write some println messages in edit logic those all executed and x value is incremented also what is problem i don't no

Comment: I still didnt understand ur problem..

Comment: if u check my code, when after enter correct id and click on edit button  else if(action.equals("edit")){} is executed and enter in to while loop status 'success' is setted and all values are setted to session,and i redirect page to index.jsp there i checking if status is success then by using id attribute if input types i set the value to text boxes.

Comment: could you pls paste the stack trace ... i think the problem is sql statement. if I've understand correctly, your using the save button (means insert) and edit button(means update)....

Comment: what should be display in the console page...

Comment: you should must mention the name like @Jmail, because your comment not  displayed in my wall...

Answer (score 0):

The problem I figured out that every time when you are comparing string, you are using **==** which is not correct so use `status.equals("str")` for this.

Edit: Second thing don't use redirect because it creates a new **request** that's why you are loosing your parameters, so use **forward** for that

Syntax:

```
pageContext.forward("index.jsp");
```

Comment: still same problem, status fail is working but success is not working,if possible plz once execute my code

Comment: Have you checked it with equals?

Comment: Ok, I am checking it.

Comment: @kumar please see the edit answer and tell me is this working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body>
 <%String status;
  status=(String)session.getAttribute("edit");
if(status.equals("fail")) //compare string with .equals not ==
{%>
<h6>there are no records with this no</h6>
<% }
%> 
   <form action="indexaction.jsp" method="post">
   Id <input type="text" name="id" id="id2"><br>
   <%
   if(status=="success")
   {%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsById("id2").value='<%=request.getAttribute("id1")%>';
   </script>
   <%} %>
   Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name2"><br>
   <%
   if(status=="success")
   {%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsById("name2").value='<%=request.getAttribute("name1")%>';
   </script>
   <%} %>
   sex <input type="text" name="sex" id="sex2"><br>
   <%
   if(status=="success")
   {%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsById("sex2").value='<%=request.getAttribute("sex1")%>';
   </script>
   <%} %>
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="save">
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="edit">
   </form>
  </body>
```